# Perl sql select all

Tags: mysql, sql, perl

This is my code

```
my $results = $dbh->selectall_hashref('SELECT * FROM sample.teachers where term like "$searchterm%"', 'teacher');
my $searchedresults= "";
foreach my $e (keys %$results) {
    print "$e\n";
    print "searching\n";
    $searchedresults = $e;
    }
    print $searchresult."\n";
```

I am trying to search from a table in mysql server. but seems like it doesn't work
I tested it using the hardcoded way by replace $searchterm with a normal string and that works. However I need to use $searchterm but i cannot figure out why it cant work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my $results = $dbh->selectall_hashref(
   'SELECT * FROM sample.teachers where term like '.$dbh->quote("$searchterm%"),
   'teacher'
);
```

or

```
my $results = $dbh->selectall_hashref(
   'SELECT * FROM sample.teachers where term like ?,
   'teacher',
   undef,
   "$searchterm%"
);
```